# Make other li elements wrap around when one li element height increases

Tags: html, css

I am working on a drop down menu. Trouble that I am facing is that, I have a 3 level of `<ul>`, and in second level when height of a `<li>` increases because it was accommodating another `<ul>` then all other `<li>` of second level do not wrap around it.

You can visualize the situation in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qdPg/1/)

when you hover your mouse over **Technology** then you would be able to see that size of **Web Design** `<li>` is greater because of another `<ul>` that it is accommodating, because of that *Typography* and *Front end* has dropped below. Is there any way to keep them wrapping around?

Html structure is like this:

```
<nav id="nav" role="navigation">
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li> <a href="?work"><span>Technology</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hot news</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sad news</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Normal news</a></li>
            <li><a href="?webdesign">Web Design</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Super power</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Aim Gain</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Acheivers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lackers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="?typography">Typography</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="?frontend">Front-End</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="?about">Personal Stuff</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:** Attaching few screenshots
This image shows present problem, see position of **Typography** and **Front-end**

[image: This image shows the problem I am facing, see **Typography** and **Front-end**]

Following image shows what I am trying to achieve, see position of **Typography** and **Front-end**

[image: This image shows what I am trying to achieve, see **Typography** and **Front-end**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qdPg/2/)

**UPD**: [JSFiddle in acc to screenshot](http://jsfiddle.net/3qdPg/5/) (Need to update CSS rules)

**UPD**: [JSFiddle example based on classes](http://jsfiddle.net/3qdPg/7/)

I've just removed the `margin-left:20px;` on `#nav li ul li > ul`

Tested on Safari 6.1 (Mac OS X 10.9) | 
**UPD**: additionally tested on Chrome (30) & FF (23.0.1) under Mac OS X 10.9

Comment: In firefox 24, Chrome and IE 10, problem is still same.

Comment: @Abhi I've additionally tested on Chrome (30) & FF (23.0.1) under Mac OS X 10.9 | Could you please provide screenshot of your problem? I think I didn't get your question

Comment: Now I see... got you. 
Here: http://jsfiddle.net/3qdPg/5/ .
But you will need to update CSS styling.

Comment: Uh oh..you have changed the html structure. HTML structure has to remain same, otherwise it will fail to serve the purpose of navigation. **Hot News**, **Normal News**, **Typography**, **Front-end**, **Sad news** and **Web design** are all parent categories, that may or may not have subcategories. Like **Web design** have subcategories but others does not have. So logically these sub-categories cannot be grouped under a ul

Comment: What you have proposed is like creating two towers of ul for two columns and put everything for that particular column inside it. I have this option open, but I am looking for another way by which *li* tags automatically arrange themselves to fill empty spaces

Comment: @Abhi without using specific classes or IDs on `li` elements to put them into different columns - this is only way. In method you trying to implement all elements will be placed in demand of theirs width and browser's CSS layout engine.

Comment: Could you please explain why - "all parent categories, that may or may not have subcategories" ??

Comment: Major problem with creating separate columns is the dynamic nature of content, I cannot control what is going to come there, so basically any `li` height could be different, so I cannot judge how many `li` can come under one column. That is why I was looking for this solution where `li` can automatically arrange themselves.
What is the other way by IDs on `li`?

Comment: In programming no way of automatically something. You have to program output to two columns, or program additional classes for `li` elements to arrange then to left or right colon. So here is no way to do something automatically without programming

Comment: @Abhi I've updated answer and added this example: http://jsfiddle.net/3qdPg/7/ solution based on additional classes, but again you have to program this behavior